# handlebars.js...dynamic object bracket selector

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am using handlebars on a particular project, and I need to be able to pick the selected option based on some dynamic values.

```
<select name="{{attribute_code}}">
    {{#each values}}
        <option value="{{value_index}}"
            {{#ifCond ../../selectedProduct.[some_attribute] '==' value_index}}selected{{/ifCond}}>
            {{label}}
        </option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

The above block is inside an `each` block which has an `attribute_code` value. In the `option` loop for the select, i need to map the value of `attribute code` to `some_attribute`. I have dug through the docs and google, and I can't seem to find a solution for this.

So for example let's say `attribute_code` has a value of `flavour`

Then I would need the expression in the option to be...
`{{#ifCond ../../selectedProduct.[flavour] '==' value_index}}selected{{/ifCond}}`

Thoughts?

Comment: So you want to access "selectedProduct" from the context two levels above? Or what exactly do you not know how to do in Handelbars?

Comment: I need the value of `some_attribute` to be equal to `attribute_code`. I have tried to do something like this for example `{{#ifCond ../../selectedProduct.[../attribute_code] '==' value_index}}selected{{/ifCond}}`

However this does not work

I have also tried...
`{{#ifCond ../../selectedProduct.[{{../attribute_code}}] '==' value_index}}selected{{/ifCond}}`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making a custom helper...

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifDynamicPropertyCond', function (object, property, operator, value, options) {
    switch (operator) {
        case '==':
            return (object[property] == value) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '!=':
            return (object[property] != value) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '!==':
            return (object[property] !== value) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '===':
            return (object[property] === value) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '<':
            return (object[property] < value) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '<=':
            return (object[property] <= value) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '>':
            return (object[property] > value) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '>=':
            return (object[property] >= value) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '&&':
            return (object[property] && value) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '||':
            return (object[property] || value) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        default:
            return options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

and then simply...

`{{#ifDynamicPropertyCond ../../selectedProduct ../attribute_code '==' value_index}}selected{{/ifDynamicPropertyCond}}`